# Running terminal commands in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line-interface, playwright

Is there anyway to run terminal commands using playwright(javascript)? Can there be a way to access the terminal through VScode? What I am trying to achieve is instead of having steps 1-10 being login steps with username and password. I have a command and or code that can reach the terminal, login and access my Org? I attached the code of the command I am trying to use.

SFDX force:org:open -u "Test@test.com"

I tried a few scenarios but cant access the terminal through the code.

What bash/shell commands would be of use for this scenario? Cant run the SFDX command in vs code without it running in the terminal.. I want it to run the SFDX command first step 1 run the command and then run the rest of the script after.

Comment: you can do it using nodejs for that. Also you can create a bash/shell script (*.sh) to do so.

Comment: do you have a package.json file in that folder?

Comment: I do have a package.json file. it only has 13 lines of code. Will this be needed? @FelipeEsteves

Comment: Please [edit] information into your question post instead of "hiding" it in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a package.json I usually add a few extra scripts in it to help me in cases like that.

So there's two ways to run those scripts using npm or yarn:

1. add the item to the scripts section in the package.json like this:

```
{
  "name": "stack-74869815",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "SFDX force:org:open -u 'Test@test.com' && command2 && comand3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and then run :

```
npm run setup
```

or

```
yarn setup
```

The second one (which I recommend the most) is to create a script and then run that script from the package.json, like this:

script file -> setup.sh (in this case is a shell script file but it could be a .bat for windows or powershell instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Running setup...'

SFDX force:org:open -u "Test@test.com"

# do other scripts stuff

echo 'Setup finished'
```

and then your package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stack-74869815",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "sh setup.sh"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This is a sample of a scripts section of one of my projects. As you can see I have both cases here:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port=4201",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "resources": "npx capacitor-resources -p android,ios",
    "build-android": "sh build-android.sh",
    "build-ios": "sh build-ios.sh",
    "ios": "npx cap sync ios && npx ionic capacitor run ios --livereload --external",
    "android": "npx cap sync android && npx ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external",
    "postinstall": "echo '!!!WARNING - replacing CAPBridgeViewController.swift - Shake fix for iOS' && cp npm-hooks/CAPBridgeViewController.swift ./node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/CAPBridgeViewController.swift"
  },
```

There is also `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts which would run before and after npm install respectfully.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just seeing this and will try it now!

Comment: @FrankieC if that works please flag the question as answered. Thx!

Comment: I believe I flagged as answered. Thank you so much! this helped me out tremendously! @felipeEsteves